# running setup method for junit only once

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have a test class to test some functions of JPA repositories, my JPA repositories are connected with H2 db, i want to populate my db with my test entites but i need to do it only once before all tests, this is my test class:

```
public class EntityRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityJPARepository EntityRepo;

    Entity entity;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
         entiti = //initializes entity with values
         EntityRepo.save(entiti);
    }    

    //some tests on repo

 }
```

the problem is that `@Before` annotiation calls it before every test method, and i dont want my entity object to duplicate in H2 db (since `save` will be called before every method), i also cant do in with annotation @BeforeClass since i need to call `save` method on @autowired repository. How can i call Setup only once before all tests but stil after repository gets autowired?

Comment: To ensure consitency of data for each test you should run in a transaction which is rolled back after each test completes. @Before will execute in the same transaction and thus any insert will rollback before next test executes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308335/before-and-transactional. You do not then need to write any code to deal with this.

Comment: adding @transactional annotation also fixes my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@Before` method, you just need a bit of checking to do:

```
public class EntityRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityJPARepository EntityRepo;

    Entity entity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
         if (entity == null) { // true only for first pass
             entity = //initializes entity with values
             EntityRepo.save(entity);
         }
    }    

    //some tests on repo

 }
```

Alternatively, you can add an `@After` method that deletes the entity.

Comment: i dont know how it not occur to me that i can delete all data from repository after each test, its the simplest solution and probably the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Spring (as is indicated by the `@Autowired` annotation), give [spring-test-dbunit](https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) a look. Alternatively, try [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/) if XML is not your thing and you'd like a Java DSL better. In any case, the idea is not to rely on your own code in setting up the test.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the annotation
private static boolean initialized = false;

```
@BeforeClass
  public static void init() {
    initialized = true;
  }
```

works the same, just for static initialisations. you should define every initialisation in there. why is that not possibe for you?

you could save in a static flag wether the method has been executed or not.

Comment: setting up a flag is a way of solving this issue but i hoped there is another, cleaner way which wouldnt require messing around with flag settings

Comment: Unit tests in different files should be independent of each other. From my experience, tests in one file often rely on a certain intialisation. before und beforeclass are excatly the concepts to be used.

Comment: I agree: the JUnit concept for doing "once" per test class is called @BeforecClass. Any other solution is like ignoring the "recommended practice". No idea why anybody would downvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the `@BeforeClass`. It is done on a static method because it is run before the instantiation of the test class. That basically means that all `@Autowired` parameters are not yet set. `@BeforeTests` method would be appreciated in the cases where you need `@Autowired` fields to be set but only want to run the method once. But a flag EG instantiated will fix this problem. It is however not very pretty...