# No transactional EntityManager found, is your test running in a transactional?

Tags: spring, kotlin, testing, entitymanager

I am writing tests for a repository, but BeforeAll annotation causes

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager found, is your test running in a transactional?
```

error. If I change it to BeforeEach the tests work, but that's not very efficient, since the same record is repeatedly written into the database. How can I fix this?

My test class:

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("testing")
class RepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var entityManager: TestEntityManager

    val data = Data(...)
    
    @BeforeAll
    @Transactional
    fun setup() {
        entityManager.persist(data)
        entityManager.flush()
    }

    @Test
    func someTest() {
        assertEquals(1,1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308335/before-and-transactional) (and my own experience) `@Transactional` has no effect on methods annotated with `@BeforeAll` and similar. To get transactional behaviour, you need to **add `@Transactional` to all the relevant `@Test` methods, or to the class as a whole** (which then applies to *every* test method).

Comment: Tried that, same result :`(

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that @BeforeAll runs before the Dependency Injection. So your EntityManager is still null when you are trying to call `entityManager.persist(data)`. Using a Constructor will result in the same problem.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. Do you know any way to make EntityManager initialize before running BeforeAll?

Comment: No, the Dependency Injection will always run after the Constructor and `@BeforeAll` Methods. I think what you are looking for is `@PostConstruct`. Replace your `@BeforeAll` with that. `@PostConstruct` runs after the Dependency Injection and your EntityManager is not null when you are trying to persist your data.

Comment: Did this, but still getting "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager found, is your test running in a transactional?" Regardless, thank you for your time

Comment: Maybe there are more Problems? Have you tried `@PostConstruct` and adding `@Transactional` to the `@Test` Methods like @gidds suggested?

Comment: Yep, the only thing that doesn't have @Transacional on it yet is entityManger